# Parent / Child SOQL WHERE condition where child field match with parent field

Tags: soql, relationships, child-to-parent

I wasn't able to find the answer on the forum: I have an easy query which involve a where condition with parent/child relation.

Here is what I'm looking to achieve:

`Select Id, ProductCode, EAN__c, Family, Product_Line__c, Name, Category__c,  Product_Type__c, **CurrencyIsoCode**, isActive, (Select Id from PricebookEntries WHERE Pricebook2Id = 'XXXXX' AND <CurrencyIsoCode of the Pricebook> = <**CurrencyIsoCode of the product**>) from product2 WHERE isActive = TRUE`

CurrencyIsoCode in **bold** should be the same.

The purpose is to match the parent currencyIsoCode field with the child CurrencyIsoCode field.

Does someone have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve this in SOQL, which doesn't allow comparison of one field to another. You can only compare fields with a constant expression.

What you *can* do is create a formula field on the PricebookEntry whose value is equal to the outcome of that comparison:

```
CurrencyIsoCode = Product2.CurrencyIsoCode
```

Then, you can reference that field in your query:

```
SELECT Id, ProductCode, EAN__c, Family, Product_Line__c, Name, Category__c,  Product_Type__c, CurrencyIsoCode, isActive, 
    (SELECT Id 
     FROM PricebookEntries 
     WHERE Pricebook2Id = 'XXXXX' AND Shares_Parent_Iso_Code__c = true) 
FROM Product2
WHERE IsActive = TRUE
```

Note that this can have the same performance implications as any other situation where you filter a query by a formula field, particularly at large data volumes.

Comment: Nice workaround! It is working perfectly.
Thanks!